# How can I get the corresponding MSI message in an interrupt?

Tags: linux, driver, interrupt, pci-e

We are using an FPGA on a PCIe card. I am able to reserve the proper resources and the MSI interrupt fires correctly. My problem is discerning the interrupt sources from: My Linux driver receives only a single MSI interrupt for different interrupt sources from the FPGA. Therefore the FPGA guys are sending the reason coded in the MSI message over the bus.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a possibility to access this message in order to get the information out of this frame in my ISR? (I know I could always check the FPGA's interrupt status register, but using the MSI message would be more elegant and would avoid additional bus access.)
2. If 1 is not possible, would switching to MSI-X solve this problem, so that I could get the information directly? (I know that MSI-X is the preferred solution, but the FPGA guys specified MSI)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you have got the answer you need by now, but I will attempt to contribute based on my understanding of MSI in the the windows driver, since it is a PCIe 2.2 standard behavior and should not be different.  I am writing a windows PCIe driver to handle MSI interrupts originating from a TI [DM8168](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320dm8168&DCMP=vs_dm8168_03182010&HQS=Other+OT+dm8168) configured as pcie endpoint.

When the FPGA device signals a regular (non msi-x) MSI interrupt, it does not actually send a 'message' in the sense that a data structure must be filled and transmitted somewhere.  MSI is achieved simply by having the FPGA write a certain data word value to one specific memory location that is shared over PCIe between host and device.  The particular memory location and data value that must be written are selected by the host's bus manager, it can't just be any an arbitrary value.

A pointer to the MSI memory location and a specific, pre-defined data value to use are set up by the bus manager in PCIe config space, so that device and host can both see them.  The MSI memory location is a physical bus address, so it must be translated to virtual address space both on device and host.

The maximum number of messages that regular (non msi-x) MSI can support must be an integral power of 2 with a maximum of 32 (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32).   For example if the FPGA supports 8 messages, then it will copy the data value (from PCIe config space) and set the lowest 3 bits to indicate the MessageID number (0-7), and then write this new value to the MSI pointer location.  If the FPGA supports 16 messages, then it must modify the lower 4 bits of the data value to indicate the messageID number (0-15).  The higher bits of the data value must not be changed.

On the receiving end in your ISR, you check the same lowest bits to see which MSI was signaled.  There is no other data or ACK associated with MSI itself; any further data is implementation-specific and must be read from memory locations or registers agreed between you and the hardware team.  In windows WDF framework drivers, this MessageID value is already masked and provided as a parameter into the [EvtInterruptIsr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback function.  I'm sure it is different in linux.

I'm a bit late on the response, but it might be useful in the future for someone else crossing this topic like I did in the last few weeks.